# Turn by turn navigation Android

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, android-maps, osmdroid

I am using OSM Mapquest maps and receiving driving directions using OSM Bonus Pack. I am unable to find how to advance and display the next upcoming direction to the user once the user the passed the the previous waypoint.

Comment: Hi Did you implemented this? please help me I have to implement same like this

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it helps you, do vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSM Bonus Pack is a third library that gives turn by turn directions on top of OSM Maps with some additional features.

https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/

UPDATE:
THIS PROJECT HAS BEEN MIGRATED TO Github

> This is the new link:
>   https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack